# Problem with missing info from the wikipedia API

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, wikipedia-api

this is my first question on StackOverflow so if I'm doing something wrong please tell me...

I've been doing some webscraping and am looking in particular for all the "Categories" certain music groups belong to in wikipedia. I am still very novice so I might be overlooking something extremely basic...

For this I am using the wikipedia API. It works great with some bands. For example if i look for Maroon 5

```
r = http.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=categories&titles=Maroon_5")
r.json()
```

it returns this JSON file

```
{'continue': {'clcontinue': '512449|Articles_with_permanently_dead_external_links',
  'continue': '||'},
 'query': {'normalized': [{'from': 'Maroon_5', 'to': 'Maroon 5'}],
  'pages': {'512449': {'pageid': 512449,
    'ns': 0,
    'title': 'Maroon 5',
    'categories': [{'ns': 14,
      'title': 'Category:1994 establishments in California'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:222 Records artists'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:A&M Records artists'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:Adam Levine'},
     {'ns': 14,
      'title': 'Category:All Wikipedia articles needing words, phrases or quotes attributed'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:All articles with dead external links'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:American pop rock music groups'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:American soul musical groups'},
     {'ns': 14,
      'title': 'Category:Articles with dead external links from February 2020'},
     {'ns': 14, 'title': 'Category:Articles with hCards'}]}}}}
```

but with a lot of other bands, like "Active Child" for example, this file is returned:

```
r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=categories&titles=Acid_Casuals")
r.json()
```

```
{'batchcomplete': '',
 'query': {'pages': {'-1': {'ns': 0, 'title': 'Acid Casuals', 'missing': ''}}}}
```

I have tried replacing the "%20" with "_" and nothing changes. Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

On a sidenote I've also noticed, that even for Maroon 5 a lot of categories are missing in the json. This is probably a related issue I'm guessing.

I would try delving into Beautifulsoup if all else fails, but I would still prefer to get this method working.

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English Wikipedia does have an article named [Maroon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maroon_5) but does not have any article titled [Acid Casuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_Casuals). The `'missing'` key in response is an indicator of that. No article, no categories.

Comment: oh my. This is silly. Yeah I wanted to look for "Active Child" and put "Acid Casuals" in the request accidentally. I'm an idiot. thanks...